# Does SMS Forward to Mac work if iPhone is turned off?

Tags: messages

I have a MacBook and an iPhone. The iPhone is setup to forward SMS to my MacBook. If the iPhone is turned off can I still send/receive SMS in Messages on my MacBook?

Answer (score 3):

No, iPhone has to be turned on in order for SMS messages to be received by it and then forwarded to your computer, or for you to send messages, which are sent back to the phone and then out to your carrier from there.